# adding actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm trying to do a project with [actionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) work on android 2.3.3 And I have installed android 4.0 and 2.3.3

I download ActionBarSherlock and unzipped in Eclipse workespace.

And then open Eclipse go to File-> New -> Project -> Android Project From Existing Code.

In the next screen select the the ActionBarSherlock folder, a list of Eclipse projects

But "library" appears in a lighter color and I can not select it
[image]

What am I doing wrong? thank you very much, sorry for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you dont have any other project called "library" in workspace. Happened to me once.

Comment: if there. but it not was created by my. 
I delete it?

Comment: it is better to just rename. Then you will be able to add this library.